# use QR code to login to website

Tags: asp.net

I am thinking of using a QR code to login to a website. This way a user doesn't have to enter a user id/password.

1. users goes to a website.
2. the website need autorisation.
3. the website present a QR code.
4. the user scans the QR code with his/her phone.

Somehow the originating website gets confirmation that the QR code was scanned by a known phone.

Now the website knows the user and the user is logged in.
This is safe because the phone is known to the site.
If needed the user can protect the phone with a PIN code or other locking system.

Does anybody know if somebody has already build such a system?
Some code would be nice :-)

Comment: a) if the user is visiting the web site using the phone how do they scan the code b) if the user is using a normal browser, how do you prevent an eavesdropper from getting in before the actual user when the code is scanned since there's no connection between the phone and the browser?

Comment: Saying "doesn't have to enter a user id/password" makes it sound like getting your phone, opening the camera/qr app, taking a snapshot & waiting for some app (and you would need an app to relay the msisdn) to do authentication is easier .. it isn't.  If for some reason you want to bind a web session to an authenticated handset, use SMS messaging.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to discuss this.
I was waiting for a email to be told there was comment on my question. I guess my mistake.

Comment: tvanfosson. a) I assume that the phone IS the authentication. So if the website can detect the phone being used and use that as the authentication than one would not need to scan a code. b) if somebody "stole" the qr code then it would be scanned by the wrong device and thus would not authenticate the user.

Comment: Alex K. I did not try and build this, so I don't know yet. But qr code reading is used, so it can't be that bad. I you would use SMS than 1) the user would have to type in the code. How is that easier. 2) sms text have costs.

Answer (score 4):

> When logging in to a site, the web server sends the
>   PC browser a QR code that encodes a cryptographic challenge; the user
>   takes a picture of the QR code with his cell phone camera which re-
>   sults in a cryptographic response sent to the server; the web server then
>   logs the PC browser in.

Excerpt from: [Secure, Consumer-Friendly Web Authentication
and Payments with a Phone](http://mobisocial.stanford.edu/papers/mobicase10s.pdf)

The have some real code too: https://github.com/Mobisocial/Snap2Pass

Comment: Here's the video of how it works: [Snap2Pass Secure Browser Login](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-9QOcDV4VZI)

All this is part of bigger thing: [The Stanford Mobile and Social Computing Research Group](http://mobisocial.stanford.edu)

Answer (score 0):

Because there are some challenges with sending data from the server to the waiting client, i.e. the page that showed the QR code we made www.qrpu.sh

This will just make some of the infrastructure easier, but the logic of the authentication is the same as in the answer from pods

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit old discussion but I was looking for a solution to this kind of problem and I found this:
[qrlogin](https://qrlogin.info/)